# como adicionar uma div com informações acima do navbar com carousel de fundo

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, carousel, nav-bar

estou com uma dificuldade que embora pareça ser simples mas não estou conseguindo chegar onde quero, estou criando um site onde tenho uma div com o cambo de idiomas, no meio a logo e um botão de reservas, eu tenho um **carousel** que deve ficar abaixo dessa div e logo abaixo tenho um **navbar**, o problema é que o **carousel** não fica embaixo ele empurra a div ou fica por cima e o navbar não funciona não clica, alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: Como deve ficar]

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.topo { 
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999; 
}
.topo .container{
  background: transparent !important;
}
.topo .row{
  background: transparent !important;
}
.nav {
  color:#fff;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color:#fff !important;
}

.navbar {
  border-width: 0px !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px !important;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0) !important;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00))) !important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%) !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%) !important;
}


 /*
Fade content bs-carousel with hero headers
Code snippet by maridlcrmn (Follow me on Twitter @maridlcrmn) for Bootsnipp.com
Image credits: unsplash.com
*/

/********************************/
/*       Fade Bs-carousel       */
/********************************/

.slider { margin-top: -100px !important; z-index: -999 !important;}

.fade-carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh; /*100vh*/
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
  height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #f39c12;
  border-color: #f39c12;
  opacity: .7;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
opacity: 1;
}

/********************************/
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.hero h1 {
  font-size: 6em;    
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
     -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
      -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
       -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
          transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
     -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
      -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
       -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
          transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}

/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #080d15;
  opacity: .7;
}

/********************************/
/*          Custom Buttons      */
/********************************/
.btn.btn-lg {padding: 10px 40px;}
.btn.btn-hero,
.btn.btn-hero:hover,
.btn.btn-hero:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border-color: #1abc9c;
  outline: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 80vh; /*100*/
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  margin-top: -100px !important;
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92?q=75&fm=jpg&s=883a422e10fc4149893984019f63c818); 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339684178-3a239570f315?q=75&fm=jpg&s=c39d9a3bf66d6566b9608a9f1f3765af);
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912?q=75&fm=jpg&s=9bf9f2ef5be5cb5eee5255e7765cb327);
}

/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
  .hero { width: 980px; }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  .hero h1 { font-size: 4em; }    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>          
<div class="topo">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        idiomas
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        logo
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        botao reserva
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Inicio do Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"><!-- navbar-fixed-top -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!--
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="">
      </a>
      -->
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#quem-somos">Quem somos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#oque-oferecemos">O que oferecemos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#depoimento">Depoimentos </a></li>
        <li><a href="#mapa">Contato</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<!--  Fim do Navbar -->

<!-- inicio carousel --> 
<div class="slider">
  <div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
    <!-- Overlay -->
    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item slides active">
        <div class="slide-1"></div>
        <div class="hero">
          <hgroup>
            <h1>We are creative</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
          </hgroup>
          <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item slides">
        <div class="slide-2"></div>
        <div class="hero">        
          <hgroup>
            <h1>We are smart</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
          </hgroup>       
          <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item slides">
        <div class="slide-3"></div>
        <div class="hero">        
          <hgroup>
            <h1>We are amazing</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
          </hgroup>
          <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim carousel -->
```

Comment: tenta usar z-index: 999; onde quer que fique por cima